# Filteration using date in PHP Codeigniter

Tags: php, date, datepicker, codeigniter-3

I'm new to Code-Igniter. I'm trying to filter data on two dates(trying to find data between two dates). I've four more filters with the date range filtration. To fetch data I've used `Stored procedures`. My procedure is working fine, if I execute it in PHPMyAdmin. If I'm filtering data with other four filters it gives me correct output, but if I apply date filter, it gives me **"No record found"**, Record is present in database.

**Here is my Model code:**

```
public function getDefectyByAreaCluster($timeframe, $area, $cluster, $statusId, $startdate, $enddate)
    {
        $query = $this->db->query("call fetch_defect_area_cluster_timeframe ($timeframe,$area,$cluster,$statusId,$startdate,$enddate)");

        if ($query) {
            $data = $query->result();
            $query->next_result(); 
            $query->free_result();
            return $data;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```

**Here is my Controller code:**

```
public function DefectList()
    {   
        $user = $this->ion_auth->user()->row();
        $data['username'] = $user->username;

        $data['user_id'] = $user->id;
        $user_id = $user->id;
        $data['groupId'] = $this->l->groupId($user_id);
        $data['group'] = $data['groupId']['0']->group_id;

        $timeframe=$this->input->post('defect_time_frame');
        $area=$this->input->post('area_id');
        $cluster=$this->input->post('cluster_id');
        $statusId=$this->input->post('defect_status');
        $startdate=$this->input->post('defect_followup_date');
        $enddate=$this->input->post('defect_followup_date');

        // $startdate=DATE_FORMAT($this->input->post(strtotime('defect_followup_date')), '%m/%d/%Y');
        // $enddate=DATE_FORMAT($this->input->post(strtotime('defect_followup_date')), '%m/%d/%Y');

        if($timeframe == ''){
            $timeframe =0;
        }       
        if($area == ''){
            $area =0;
        }
        if($cluster == ''){
            $cluster =0;
        }  
        if($statusId == ''){
            $statusId =0;
        }   
        if($startdate == ''){
            $startdate =0;
        }
        if($enddate == ''){
            $enddate =0;
        }

        $data['areas'] = $this->p->area();
        $data['clusters'] = $this->p->cluster();

        //$data['defectslist'] = $this->p->defectList();
        $data['defectStatus'] =$this->p->selectDefectStatus();
        $data['defecttimeframe'] =$this->p->selectDefectTimeframe();
        $data['defectslist'] = $this->p->getDefectyByAreaCluster($timeframe, $area, $cluster, $statusId, $startdate, $enddate);
        // echo "<pre>";
        // print_r($data['defectslist']);
        // echo "</pre>";
        // exit();
        $data['title'] = 'Property Defects List';

        $this->load->view('template/header', $data); 
        $this->load->view('Property/defect_list', $data); 
        $this->load->view('template/footer'); 
    }
```

**Here is my view code:**

```
<div class="form-group">&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
            <label>FUP Start Date:</label>
            <div class="input-group date">
            <!-- <div class="input-group-addon">
            <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
            </div> -->
            <input type="text" name="defect_followup_date" class="form-control pull-right" id="datepicker3" />
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <div class="form-group">&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
            <label>FUP End Date:</label>
            <div class="input-group date">
            <!-- <div class="input-group-addon">
            <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
            </div> -->
            <input type="text" name="defect_followup_date" class="form-control pull-right" id="datepicker4" />
            </div>
        </div>
```

**Note:** I'm storeing my `defect_followup_date` in `VARCHAR` format in database.

I'm use datepicker to select dates, How I can convert that datepicker value ('mm/dd/yyyy') to match with VARCHAR value('mm/dd/yyyy') format ?

Any kind of help is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm storing my defect_followup_date in VARCHAR format in database. this is wrong. don't use varchar for dates use date or datetime datatype. because it will create issues when compare dates

Comment: I had tried with datetime datatype but no output. and when i'm executing my SP it gives me proper result.

Comment: but that is wrong approach because you can not compare dates with varchar data type

Comment: Ok , I changed varchar to date time, but how can I access value from datepicker and compare to datetime datatype. Is there any wrong in my code. Thanks adv.

Comment: can you add query with date filet. database base filter follows YYYY-mm-dd you need to pass date in this format only.

Comment: hi prasanna , but how?? plz check my code. I'm using datepicker.